# How to add an attribute to all outgoing Spans (Java)

Tags: java, open-telemetry

If I understand correctly, I should be able to use an opentelemetry Resource to attach custom Attributes to outgoing Spans. I think the syntax should be something like

```
Resource resource = Resource.create(Attributes.builder().put("key", "value").build());
SdkTracerProvider sdkTracerProvider = SdkTracerProvider.builder().setResource(resource).build;
```

Questions:

How do I set that TracerProvider as the default provider for my application?

If I do so, will it add that attribute to the default set of attributes attached to Spans, or will it replace them?

Also, if I do so, would I still be able to use the `Span.current()` syntax to access the current Span, or would I need to access the current Span through the Tracer?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I set that TracerProvider as the default provider for my application?

That depends on how your application is accessing the TracerProvider, and whether or not you're using the otel java agent:

- If using the otel java agent, you'll need to use an [agent extension](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/examples/extension/README.md) to customize the SDK that the agent installs.
- Else if you're using [autoconfigure](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/tree/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure) to install the SDK, you can use various [customization methods](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/f4d464a1c03b75b58ef4ce58e88c69f0fe89c9dd/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/sdk/autoconfigure/AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdkBuilder.java#L149) or [implement one of the SPIs](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/tree/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure-spi).
- Else if you're configuring the SDK directly, you can do what you've described.

Once you've configured SDK, you need to make sure instrumentation is accessing it. The SDK installed by otel java agent is used by all installation it installs. If not using the agent, you can manually pass the SDK to the relevant instrumentation. If its not practical to manually pass the SDK, you can use GlobalOpenTelemetry, which has static accessor for setting / getting the OpenTelemetry instance, although this is discouraged.

You should also consider whether the resource is the appropriate place for the attribute. The resource is attached to all records exported by the SDK, but its generally reserved for attributes that describe the source of the telemetry. If the attributes describe the record itself, consider adding a custom [SpanProcessor](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/f4d464a1c03b75b58ef4ce58e88c69f0fe89c9dd/sdk/trace/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/sdk/trace/SpanProcessor.java) to add the attribute to individual spans.